# Придаточное цели в назывном предложении

Tags: синтаксис, спп, сложное-предложение, придаточное-предложение

*Положение ваших партнёров в данный момент слегка затруднительное. Чтобы ваше не было таким же, вот несколько рекомендаций.*

Корректно ли использовать придаточное цели в назывном предложении, где нет действия (обычно именно действие совершается или процесс происходит с какой‑то целью)?

Comment: Я полагаю, что в Вашем СПП нет назывного предложения.

Comment: @Sharon А чем тогда является "вот несколько рекомендаций"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Положение ваших партнёров в данный момент слегка затруднительное. Чтобы ваше не было таким же, вот несколько рекомендаций.**

1) Это СПП с придаточным цели. В придаточном предложении выражается цель субъекта, а в главном – действие субъекта для достижения этой цели.

Соответственно,  **назывное предложение не может находиться в позиции главного,** так как действие оно не предполагает.

2) Главное предложение: **Вот (вам) несколько рекомендаций.**

Скорее всего, это **неполное эллиптическое предложение** вида "подлежащее – пропущенное дополнение", которое действие подразумевает, но конкретно не называет.

3) Почему это в принципе не назывное предложение? Об это можно прочитать в прилагаемой статье.

**Приложение: о назывных (номинативных) предложениях**
https://studfiles.net/preview/3488542/page:2/

Именительный падеж является формальным признаком номинативного предложения, однако это не решающий фактор, так как **далеко не каждое имя способно образовать номинативное предложение.** Номинативные предложения **лексически ограничены словами, способными передавать значение бытийности.** Поэтому в формировании номинативных предложений основную роль играет семантическая природа имени...

￼

Comment: _Скорее всего, это неполное эллиптическое предложение вида "подлежащее – пропущенное дополнение", которое действие подразумевает, но конкретно не называет._ Тут не только дополнение пропущено, но и сказуемое, если вы отрицаете статус назывного предложения. Полное предложение бы выглядело так: "Чтобы ваше не было таким же, вот вам даётся несколько рекомендаций", верно?

Comment: Для эллиптического предложения (в отличие от неполного) характерна определенная структура. Это двусоставное предложение вида подлежащее - дополнение, подлежащее - обстоятельство.  Там нет сказуемого, но при это действие подразумевается. Вы можете подставить любое сказуемое (дается. предлагается).